# How do I inject something in a variable?

Tags: nestjs

I have a service provided in a module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SomethingService } from './something.service';

@Module({
  providers: [SomethingService]
})
export class SomethingModule {}
```

In a different file, I want to inject this service in a constant. With `typedi` I'd do something like the following:

```
import { Container } from 'typedi';
const service = Container.get(SomethingService);
```

How can I achieve that with Nest.js?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on what you're trying to do? I'm not sure I understand `I want to inject this service in a constant`.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I want to inject in the service constant an instance of SomethingService

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in another provider, or a controller? Or are you trying to do this outside of Nest's DI system?

Comment: It's in another provider

Answer (score 0):

Nest's natural DI system does dependency injection via the `constructor`. Injecting a value usually looks like this:

```js
@Injcetable()
export class SomeAwesomeClass {

  constructor(private readonly somethingService: SomethingService) {}
}
```

Nest figures out what you are injecting via the class name through a lot of reflection . If you need to do [injection to a property](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers#property-based-injection) instead for some reason, you can do something like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SomeAwesomeClass {

  @Inject()
  private somethingService: SomethignService;
}
```

And Nest *should* be able to resolve the injection, though normally constructor based injection is preferred as it is more reliable and the standard approach with most Nest applications.

Make sure that in your module metadata, you export the provider as well, and then import the provider's module into the module that the provider will be injected in. E.g.

```js
@Module({
  providers: [SomethingService],
  exports: [SomethingService],
})
export class SomethingModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [SomethingModule],
  providers: [OtherService],
})
export class OtherModule {}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class OtherService {
  constructor(private readonly somethingService: SomethingService) {}
}
```